# How do I tell Visual Studio Code not to format text between two delimiters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is a typical block of html that I am working with:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        \begin{align*}
            x_1^\phantom{1} &= \phantom{-}1 \\
            x_2^\phantom{1} &= -10 \\
            x_3^\phantom{1} &= \phantom{-}11 \\
        \end{align*}
    </li>
</ol>
```

The code in the middle is a snippet of LaTeX that gets rendered on the client with MathJax. But whenever I have Visual Studio Code format the document it inlines the entire block of LaTeX:

```
\begin{align*} x_1^\phantom{1} &= \phantom{-}1 \\ x_2^\phantom{1} &= -10 \\ x_3^\phantom{1} &= \phantom{-}11 \\ \end{align*}
```

Can I tell Visual Studio Code not to format text between two delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr use `<code></code>`.

There are other options in File > Preferences > Settings:

```
// List of tags, comma separated, where the content shouldn't be reformatted. 'null' defaults to the 'pre' tag.
"html.format.contentUnformatted": "pre,code,textarea",
```